# Problems with renderincontext with QLPreviewController in iOS6

Tags: ios

I have searched the internet to answer this question, but not found the answer yet.

I am writing an app that displays docs using QLPrieviewController.  I want to take the screen and duplicate it off to an external display.   I have it working for ios5 with code below.  This code no longer works in ios6.

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.previewController.view.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
    [self.previewController.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * clonedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [mirrorWebPageView setImage: clonedImage];
```

I tried to use render the front window to see what I would get using the following code.

```
    NSArray * currentwindows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]; 
    UIWindow *trythisone = [currentwindows objectAtIndex:0];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(trythisone.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
    [trythisone.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * clonedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [mirrorWebPageView setImage: clonedImage];
```

I get the navbar and the bottom tool bar displayed, but the content of the QLPreviewController is not displayed in the view.

I have read that there are some issues with RenderIncontext, but have not been able to identify if this is my problem.

Any ideas on how to solve this would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I have encountered the same...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do a screen capture programatically on iOS6 it will only capture the background view. On iOS5 it would work.  It could be a security feature that prevents a program from capturing what you are viewing and send it off to somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, because the previewed document is not displayed by your process anymore on recent versions of iOS. The preview mechanism is handled by another process.